# Enable AWS Glue Continuous Logging from create_job

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

I'm creating a Glue Job using boto3 [`create_job`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_job). I was interested to pass a parameter to enable [Continuous Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging.html) (no filter) for this new Job.

Unfortunately neither [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html) or [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_job) I can find any useful parameter to enable it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find solution to this?

Comment: @PratikGoenka not yet, sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way to do it, it's similar to other arguments, you just need to pass these log related arguments in Default Arguments like -

```
glueClient.create_job(
            Name="testBoto",
            Role="Role_name",
            Command={
                'Name': "some_name",
                'ScriptLocation' : "some_location"
            },
            DefaultArguments={
                "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "true",
                "--enable-continuous-log-filter": "true"
            }
        )
```

Comment: that's great! How did you find these parameters?

Comment: It's mentioned here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging-enable.html